# Regular Expression and Logic for Date Validation

Tags: php, validation, date

I have this code for date validation:

```
if(!preg_match('/^[0-3]?[0-9]\/[0-1]?[0-9]\/[0-9]{4}$/',$Date))
{
     echo "<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=style.css /><b><font color=red size=2>Please Check Preferred Date </font><a href=index.php> Click here to Go Back .</a> "; 
     exit();
}
```

But when I pass a date with format of `dd/mm/yyyy`, it displays the error message. Is there something wrong with the regular expression?

Comment: where you find this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try this. (dd/mm/YYYY) Eg: 06/12/2014

```
   if (preg_match('\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}', $input))
   {
      return true; // it matched, return true
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }
```

Comment: actually how its work ...if(!preg_match('/^[0-3]?[0-9]\/[0-1]?[0-9]\/[0-9]{4}$/',$Date))

Comment: What actually you need ... explain clearly...

Comment: how the function works (preg_match)

Comment: So `99/99/2014` or `0/0/2015` are valid dates?

Answer (score 0):

It works.

```
$Date = '25/12/2014';
if(!preg_match('/^[0-3]?[0-9]\/[0-1]?[0-9]\/[0-9]{4}$/',$Date))
{
    echo "<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=style.css /><b><font color=red size=2>Please Check Prefered Date 124</font><a href=index.php> Click here to Go Back .</a> "; 
    exit();
}
```

You can test here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: actually how its work ...  if(!preg_match('/^[0-3]?[0-9]\/[0-1]?[0-9]\/[0-9]{4}$/',$Date))